# Could not determine the dependencies for all tasks with robolectric gradle plugin

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

after modifying my gradle build file like written in the docu I get the following error for all of my tasks:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':android:testDebug'.

it is a subproject called android so might be just testDebug for others
using gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.+

anybody knows what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after using gradle 1.6 instead of 1.7 it is working

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: this is the answer - the problem was that a newer gradle version broke the plugin

Answer (score 1):

A [pull request was made on the plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin/pull/26) that essentially handles Gradle 1.7/1.8. The owner hasn't pushed it to the maven repo, so you can't use the version on the maven repo just yet.

I checked out the source code from github and added it as a manual dependency in my libraries with gradle. That should get you going.